# how to implement iTestContext listener without adding to method argument testng(from XML) for PDFBox utility

Tags: selenium-webdriver, testng, listener

I am automating a salesforce application using Selenium TestNG. I am implementing a utility using apache PDFBox where i paste all my screenshots into a PDF to make client happy .

My logic is i create screenshots in each method with 1.png , 2.png etc until n.png and paste them in pdf using pdfbox methods.

The problem is my number of screenshots are variable so i implemented iTestContext where i set a variable counter to maximum number pass them to my after method where i retrieve the counter , and those number of screenshots are pasted- something like this

```java
Class Login {

    @Test
    mymethod(ItestContext context){
        commonfunctions.savescreenshot(1.png);
        commonfunctions.savescreenshot(2.png);
        commonfunctions.savescreenshot(n.png);
        context.setAttribute("Counter", "n");
    }

    @AfterMethod
    myaftermethod(){
        String PATH = //Path of my test method    
        String MethodCounter = (String)context.getAttribute("Counter");
        PDFUtility.addImagetoPDF(PATH,Integer.parseInt(MethodCounter) );
    }
}
```

The problem is i have many methods that i need to implement and i dont want `ITestContext` listener as argument to each method.Can i pass it in xml file and use it for all methods?

Hope i have provided all details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to get hold of the current `ITestContext` object (which is a representation of the current `<test>` tag being executed), you don't need to pass it as a parameter to your `@Test` method.

You can get access to it from within a `@Test` annotated test method via something like this:

```java
org.testng.ITestContext context = 
org.testng.Reporter.getCurrentTestResult().getTestContext();
```

This way you dont need to pass the `org.testng.ITestContext` object as a parameter to your `@Test` method.

> Can i pass it in xml file and use it for all methods?

No you cannot pass the `ITestContext` object via the xml file.

Comment: Also i guess i need to ask another question but just asking how can i increment counter independently for each method instead of manually giving 1 to n , my screenshot method resides in seperate utility,no issues if it cant be answered here

Comment: Try initialising an `AtomicInteger` with `0` and keep incrementing it.